# Rendering related records side by side in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I am trying to render the following JSON object on angular 7 UI.

TermDetail object contains `LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel` and `LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel` objects. The two are related by `LegalParentClassId`. What I am looking at that the related objects should render side by side. At the moment it is showing only the matching record.How do I achieve this in angular

Here is the jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/b69dphxr/

So for example  if I have the following records:

```
Id     Name  
23456  Test

Id     Name 
23457  Test1

Id     Name   LegalParentClassId
23458  Test2  23456
```

It should then in the UI render in the following sequence

```
23456,  23458,  23457
```

JSON

```
{"LiqLockupType":null,"LiqDurationMonths":null,"LiqGateSource":null,"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":[{"Description":"Class B","AuditSummary":"skeeling Jun 11, 2018","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":11166,"FundId":5508,"FundClassType":1,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":null,"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":45,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":3,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":"12 M,0.03|","LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":null},{"Description":"Class A","AuditSummary":"skeeling Jun 11, 2018","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":11167,"FundId":5508,"FundClassType":1,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":null,"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":45,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":3,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":"12 M,0.03|","LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":null},{"Description":"Class D","AuditSummary":" ","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":13714,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":null,"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":45,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":null,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":null},{"Description":"Class B","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 04, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"dmukerji May 28, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"rmenon Jun 04, 2019","Id":13717,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":null,"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":46,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":5,"LockupTypeName":"No Lock","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":0,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":30,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":2,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","HoldbackPercentage":0,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":0,"IncentiveFeeRate":30,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":0,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":1,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":"Management Fee","FeeComments":"New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":null},{"Description":"Class A","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 04, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"dmukerji May 28, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"kweigand Jan 16, 2019","Id":13713,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":null,"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":2,"SubVotingName":"Yes","SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":46,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":5,"LockupTypeName":"No Lock","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":0,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":30,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":2,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","HoldbackPercentage":0,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":0,"IncentiveFeeRate":30,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":0,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":1,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":"Management Fee","FeeComments":"New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":null},{"Description":"Class B1","AuditSummary":"kweigand Feb 19, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"kweigand Feb 19, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"fblack Nov 21, 2018","Id":13716,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":null,"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":46,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":5,"LockupTypeName":"No Lock","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":22,"SoftDurationMonthsName":"72","LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":0,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":30,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":2,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","HoldbackPercentage":0,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":0,"IncentiveFeeRate":30,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":0,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":1,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":"Management Fee","FeeComments":"New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":null},{"Description":"Class C","AuditSummary":"kweigand Feb 19, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"kweigand Feb 19, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"fblack Nov 21, 2018","Id":13715,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":null,"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":46,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":5,"LockupTypeName":"No Lock","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":0,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":30,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":2,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","HoldbackPercentage":0,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":0,"IncentiveFeeRate":30,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":0,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":1,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":"Management Fee","FeeComments":"New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":null},{"Description":"TestRanjit100","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 04, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":28424,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":2,"PrimaryCurrencyName":"USD","OtherCurrencyName":null,"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":null,"RedsFrqncyName":null,"RedsNoticeDays":null,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":null,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":null,"LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":null,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":null,"LegalParentClassId":null}],"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":[{"Description":"Class A","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 05, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"dmukerji May 28, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"kweigand Jan 16, 2019","Id":28443,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":4,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":null,"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":2,"SubVotingName":"Yes","SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":46,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":5,"LockupTypeName":"No Lock","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":0,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":30,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":2,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","HoldbackPercentage":0,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":0,"IncentiveFeeRate":30,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":0,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":1,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":"Management Fee","FeeComments":"New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":13713}],"Currencies":null,"LiqVoting":null,"LiqHotIssue":null,"LiqRedsFrequency":null,"LiqTypeOfDays":null,"LiqFrequencys":null,"LiqHighWaterMarks":null,"LiqHurdleRateBasis":null,"LiqHurdleRateIndex":null,"FeeDicountTypes":null,"ManagerStrategies":null,"FundClassType":null,"Funds":null,"FirmFunds":null}
```

UI

```
<table class="fundClassesTable table-striped" border="1">
  <tr *ngFor="let c of ColumnNames">
    <th class="tableItem bold">{{ c }}</th>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let f of data">
         <ng-container *ngFor="let s of data1;">
             <ng-container *ngIf="f.Id == s.LegalParentClassId">  
      <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[0]">{{f.Description}}</td>
      <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[1]">{{f.AuditSummary}}</td>
      <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[2]">{{f.Id}}</td>
    </ng-container>
     </ng-container> 
  </ng-container>

  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Your issue is unfortunately very tied to your specific code, and not likely to be of use for anyone else. Please try to reduce your problem to small reproducible issue so that the community can help you - and it benefits the community. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have tried to put as minimal code as possible and it will definitely help the community

Comment: I do not share your point of view.

Comment: All I am asking here is there are two objects that have related record and need help to rendering it in a sequence

Comment: I have created jsfiddle on your request https://jsfiddle.net/b69dphxr/

Comment: "All I am asking here is ...". Exactly. So come up with a small 5-10 lines example if you want someone to help you. Nobody is going to go through your 50+ long lines of code/data, even in jsfiddle. Feel free to follow this advice or not, just my 2 cents to help you.

Comment: Its just 12 lines of logic code and rest is mock data that I am supplying to it. I am not sure what you need more than this.

Comment: I have simplified the code further. Please let me know if thats ok